# Find single occurrence of an element in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find single occurrence of an element in an array. But it only shows for 1 element. Where is the logic going wrong?

```
function findSingle(array){
  var arrayCopy = array.slice(0);
  var x;
  var y = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    x = arrayCopy.splice(i, 1)
    if(arrayCopy.includes(array[i]) === false){
      console.log(array[i] + " is single")
    }
    arrayCopy = arrayCopy.concat(x)
   }
 }

findSingle([1, 3, 3, 6])
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want to find ALL elements that only appear once in your array? So in your example, the expected answer is `[1, 6]`?

Comment: if I had [1, 3, 3, 6, 8, 4, 6] then answer is 1, 8, 4 because they all appear only once in the array.

Comment: `const findSingle=a=>a.filter((v,i)=>a.lastIndexOf(v)===array.indexOf(v));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added some `console.logs` to see what was happening and the problem is that you're changing the order of elements in `arrayCopy`. And so `6` is never checked.

```
Checking for [ 1 ]
arrayCopy is [ 3, 3, 6 ]
1 is single
After adding to arrayCopy [ 3, 3, 6, 1 ]
Checking for [ 3 ]
arrayCopy is [ 3, 6, 1 ]
After adding to arrayCopy [ 3, 6, 1, 3 ]
Checking for [ 1 ]
arrayCopy is [ 3, 6, 3 ]
After adding to arrayCopy [ 3, 6, 3, 1 ]
Checking for [ 1 ]
arrayCopy is [ 3, 6, 3 ]
After adding to arrayCopy [ 3, 6, 3, 1 ]
```

You can probably use a frequency map to find the number of occurrences in each element and then filter keys that occur only once.

```
function findSingle(array){
  var freqs = {};
  array.forEach(n => {
    if (!(n in freqs)) freqs[n] = 1;
    else freqs[n] += 1;
  });
  return Object.keys(freqs).filter(k => freqs[k] === 1);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a double [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove numbers that appear more than once:

```js
    function findSingle(arr) {
      return arr.filter(i => arr.filter(j => i === j).length === 1)
    }
    
    const result = findSingle([1, 3, 3, 6, 8, 4, 6])
    console.log(result) // [1, 8, 4]
```

Bear in mind that this will only work for Numbers and other [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) because of [the way that Javascript evaluates equality and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Comment: expected answer for input `[1, 3, 3, 6, 8, 4, 6]` is `1, 8, 4`

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by creating an object that could map element and its occurrence.
So here is a code

```
function findSingle(arr){
    var counts = {};
    var singles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var num = arr[i];
        counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
    }
    for(var num in counts) {
        if(counts[num] == 1)
            singles.push(num);
    }
    return singles.map(x => Number(x));
}
```

The output of `findSingle([1, 3, 3, 6])` will be

```
[1, 6]
```

**Note** This can work with string too but it may be numbers. For example,  `["1", "3", "3", "6"]`